# How to map Enums to a separate table with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, mapping

I currently have a Hibernate mapping which works as follows:

```
Table 'TASK':
  id int, name varchar, status varchar
```

Enum

```
public enum TaskStatus {
  INVALID, INITIAL, IN_PROGRESS, PAUSED, DONE;
}
```

Type

```
@Entity
public class Task {

  @Column(name = "STATUS")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private TaskStatus status;

  public TaskStatus getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(TaskStatus status) {
      this.status = status;
  }
}
```

I want to change this to save all possible status in one table such as:

```
Table 'TASK_STATUS':
  id int, status varchar

Table 'TASK':
  id int, name varchar, status_id int foreign key
```

Is it possible to define a mapping for the enum type using Hibernate Annotations and a way to map it to the Task Type. I still want the Java implementation to look like the one above (having the TaskStatus property instead of an int property) so i can comfortably use:

```
myTask.setStatus(TaskStatus.DONE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if value set of status_id match to the ordinal of enum, simply use following:

```
@Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL )
```

Correct table structure (FK, TASK_STATUS table) will not be automatically generated by Hibernate.

If numerical values do not match to ordinal, then you have to create custom type. One example is given [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingAnEnumWithAVARCHARColumn), but you will of course use integer type instead of varchar.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using ordinal. Thanks for your link. I'm still trying to find a version which is easy to read. I want to use the enum to make things simpler than my previous 'public static final int STATUS_X' version.

Comment: Then you unfortunately need custom type.

Comment: Seems to be no way around it. Hope a simpler way will be possible some time soon.